# How to find m so that RSA cipher end with '\x00'+SpesificString , if we freely input the plaintext?

Tags: rsa, padding, chosen-plaintext-attack

I have an RSA encryption with public key $(3,n)$ with 2048 bits modulus $n$.

I want to find the value of the plaintext $m$ so that the ciphertext (in bytes representation) value ends with `\x00+MySpesificString`.

$ciphertext = pow(m,e,n)$

where $m$ can be any string and ciphertext has the following format

`any string+\x00+MySpesificString`

How I can find the possible value of $m$?

Comment: Welcome to cryptography. Did you try the cube root attack?

Comment: i did, but unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: nope. m has no structure, it can be anything. 
But the cipher did. the cipher structure is anything as a prefix , and end with suffix = '\x00'+MySpecificString. 

for example cipher = aaaaabbbbb\x00+MySpecificString, cc22244\x00+MySpecificString, etc

Comment: Is this homework or CTF?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is homework (I have time imagining that this is a problem that you need to solve; if it is, turn "use real RSA padding").

Since this is assumed to be homework, I'll give you the initial steps, and let you do the rest of the work.

First off, what you're asking is to find a value $m$ such that $(m^3 \bmod n) \bmod 2^{136
} = \text{"\x00"} + \text{"MySpesificString"}$; noting hat $\text{"\x00"} + \text{"MySpesificString"}$ consists of 136 bits.

Now, we are not told anything about $n$, except that it is "2048 bits", that is, it is in the range $2^{2048} > n \ge 2^{2047}$.  Now, we want a value of $m$ that would work for any $n$ in this range; we can do this if $m^3 < 2^{2047}$, and so $m^3 \bmod n = m^3$

Hence, we're looking for a value $m$ for which $m < \sqrt[3]{2^{2047}} \approx 2^{682.333}$ and for which $m^3 \equiv \text{"MySpesificString"} \pmod{2^{136}}$.

That may still sound daunting; however can we find a value $m$ that satisfies the last equations modulo $2^1$?  And, if we have a value $m$ that satisfies the last equation modulus $2^k$, can we find a value $m'$ that satisfies it modulo $2^{k+1}$?

Comment: Actually i know the value of n , but it too long to write here.

The specific string's len is 14 bytes. with '\x00' will be 15 bytes long.

The ciphertext's len is can be any long, the prefix in ciphertext ( before '\x00' ) is can be anything.

ex:
it can be '4612864\x00'+ $(My 14 len Spesific String)$, 

or

'zx\x00'+ $(My 14 len Spesific String)$ ,

or anything fullfil the structure.

For the m value, it can be anything, and any length.

It might be more than 1 possible value of m, since the ciphertext's prefix is can be different for every possible ciphertext.

Comment: @user81147: yes, I understand the problem.  Did you go through the steps I outlined on how to solve it?